# Another expression for pledge my first born?

Tags: expressions

Does anyone know other expressions for "promise you the moon", or "pledge my first born", etc. I have a difficult client I need to say this to and I want to sound clever or witty. :) Thank you

Comment: The Moon to promise sounds like the promising of impossible, don't you think. What exactly do you mean to say? That you'll do the best you can?

Comment: "pledge my first born" to a difficult client sounds like a promise you might regret, not at all witty or clever.

Comment: Perhaps "promise you the moon" would be good, as it is a promise you cannot deliver. That leaves future demands open to negotiation.

Answer (score 1):

The cliche phrase is "I will bend over backwards", though I don't know how clever or witty that will make you sound.

Other stock phrases :

I will go the extra mile.

I will give it 110%.